# a class in a list item in jquery tabs cant be reached by CSS

Tags: jquery, css

This is my html code :

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#gallery">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About Me</a></li>
        <li class="gold"><a href="#book">All About Love</a></li>
        <li class="gold"><a href="#fashion">Fashion Corner</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Notice that i have a `class="gold"` in the last two `li`

Now i want to change the color for this class, so i tried :

```
#tabs li .gold{
    color:#CCFF00;
}
```

and

```
.gold{
    color:#CCFF00;
}
```

But none of them is working. Please kindly help me and explain a little bit, why those code is not working.

For your information, `#tabs li` selector is **working** perfectly.

Thanks for your help :D

Comment: why a downvote again --a

Comment: tip: if you use chrome or safari you can open up the console by inspecting the element by a right click and open it, on the left you see your markup and on the right the css codes, so you can find out how to select the desired one best. even nice, its writing which line of code the css was written

Comment: @codelio okay, i will try it (i use firebug, i will try chrome) Thanks:D

Comment: firebug has the same feature, but kind of difficult to see as beginer :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get rid of this space between your class and the corresponding element, remember the hirarchy of reading the codes is important for your browser, later statments overwrite earlier onces if they match the same selectors.

```
<style>
#tabs li a {
   /*here you style your anchor*/
    color: #CC0000;
}

#tabs li.gold a {
    /*here you style the golden one after the standard is given above */
    color: #CCFF00;
}

#tabs li { 
    /*here you would style your text inside li,
      but not the anchors inherited styling from the browser */
} 
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Its working (i will accept your answer in the next 5 minutes, the system wish that). However, why do i need to add "a"? My class is in the li, so #tabs li should be working (but its not)

Comment: maybe you forgott that `<li>` cant be styled like you want, because `a` has an inherited styling from the browser even if you have text outside of `a`.

Comment: Thanks Sir. I even dont know about that. But the people here seems not very friendly, a beginner question - and it will be downvoted.

Thanks for your help :D

Comment: dont worry just go forward, stack is not only for coding dude's, also for beginners who bring fresh or classic problems to us. and really usefull are this coding helper webpages like http://tinker.io http://jsbin.com and so on. but the famous jsfiddle is kind of slow :(

Answer (score 1):

You need to change to

```
#tabs li.gold{
color:#CCFF00;
}
```

and

.gold{
    color:#CCFF00;

It is working fine. Try  this http://jsfiddle.net/rajeswarik/FaKv5/1/

Answer (score 1):

If gold only applies to these li's , 
you can directly write :

```
.gold{
    color:red;
}
```

else

```
#tabs li.gold {
   color:red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but its not working. Please see my accepted answer. Thanks!